# How to correct add variables in const char type?

Tags: c++

I copied following functions out of a library.

```
int sqlite3_open(const char *filename, sqlite3 **ppDb));

void sql_stmt(const char* stmt) {
  char *errmsg;
  int   ret;

  ret = sqlite3_exec(db, stmt, 0, 0, &errmsg);

  if(ret != SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("Error in statement: %s [%s].\n", stmt, errmsg);
  }
}
```

now i have tried to add variables to some database queries like this test funtion:

```
void test(const char database , const char query){
  sqlite3_open("/sdcard/" + database);
  sql_stmt("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + query +  "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar , baz)");
}
```

How to correct implement variables in the `const char*` text?

```
test("test_db.db", "test_table");
```

the function above is of course not working, but i dont know how to solve it correct...

Comment: your test function has wrong parameter types. `const char` is a single character, there is no way to pass strings to your `test`. Did you mean `const char*` ? Why not `std::string` (if this is C++)?

Comment: i use arduino IDE which is C++ i guess.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ this can be very easily solved by using `std::string` instead of `const char *`.

```
#include <string>

void test(const std::string& database , const std::string& query){
    sqlite3_open(("/sdcard/" + database).c_str());
    sql_stmt(("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + query +  "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar , baz)").c_str());
}
```

Comment: thanks a million. fixed my issue!
unfortunately im not experienced enough to solved it on my own.